# Why gitlab uses absolute URL on pages

Tags: gitlab

I installed gitlab on my server. Server has 2 network cards, for external network and for internal network. The problem is that on gitlab pages some elements like group avatar have absolute path, and when I visit page from external network, I see links to internal networks.

Example. My server has 2 IP, for internal network `192.168.104.112` and for external network `173.194.113.2`. In gitlab settings (`gitlab.yml`) I set address `192.168.104.112`. Then I open address `173.194.113.2` in browser and can not see any project image, because all that images has absolute path to internal network like `https://192.168.104.112/uploads/project/avatar/3/av.jpg`.

Why does absolute path used for images? Why don't they replace it with address from `HTTP` request?

I can't find workaround for it.

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't set the address to `173.194.113.2` in gitlab's settings?

Comment: I can not connect to `173.194.113.2` from internal network. So I get the same problem when set the address to `173.194.113.2`.

Comment: I think you shouldn’t ask “_Why_ does it behave like this?” but rather “_How_ do I get it to work under these conditions?” Would it be possible for you to use a DNS server which serves the internal IP address when queried from the internal network and the external IP address to the public?

Comment: @hfs, thank your for your suggestion. I use DNS server. For now I understand that is is very important have own DNS server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s now [GitLab issue #2952](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2952) for this problem, without a solution at the moment.

Comment: I think it will be closed without solving. gitlab comes with gitlab-ci in package, and dns name used for make decision which service client wants to use. Also mails that gitlab send to clients contain links to gitlab. DNS server is the most comfortable solution in this situation.

Comment: I edited gitlab sources to fix absolute path for images. But it is not only problem with different IP addressed. DNS server resolved all problems I met.